# Is "tree" command not available for Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, command, tree

I tried to execute "`tree`" under Kali Linux, but it tells me command not found.

I thought "`tree`" was a standard command for all Linux OS, do I need to install it or is there a substitute for Kali Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it says the command isn't found, you need to install it:

```
apt-get install tree
```

`tree` isn't installed by default on Debian derivatives.

Comment: To a new kali user, isn't always true! I tried to run the `adduser` command and the console told me the command wasn't found. `man adduser` as a second test told me it was probably there. `sudo` made it work.

Comment: @tapzx2 that’s normal, `adduser` is an administrator command and isn’t on the default `PATH`. `tree` is on the default `PATH`, `sudo` won’t make any difference to its availability in a default setup.